# How to redirect old permalinks to ones generated by [WP-Hashed-ID] plugin?

Tags: permalinks, redirect

I've changed the permalink for WordPress post. Old permalink structure was using the 'post_id' and new one is hashed post id using the plugin WP-Hashed-ID. How can I enable redirection from links generated by old permalinks to ones generated by [WP-Hashed-ID] plugin?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the number of posts that you have, you might just use a plugin like [Redirection](https://wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/). It's easy and straightforward, if time consuming.

Good luck!

Comment: So you are saying, if I enabled WP-Hashed-ID, Redirection plugin will auto redirect old post links to new ones? I was afraid of trying to be honest as the website is huge. There is also Yoast SEO premium, does it do the trick as well?

Comment: "...will auto redirect old post links to new ones?"

No, it won't auto, it's manual and time consuming. And, to my understanding, Yoast won't auto re-direct, but I haven't used it for that outcome, so I can't say whether it'll be helpful or not.

Comment: Is there any RewriteRule which can help with redirecting from %post_id% to %hashed_id& ?

Comment: There may be, but I don't know it. That's why I use Redirection :D